# Is Attain for Deno.js simillar to Express for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, deno

I am trying to use [Deno](https://deno.land/), and I've came to a script called [Attain](https://deno.land/x/attain), which looks so much similar to Express.

Express snippet:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Attain snippet:

```
import { App, Router } from "https://deno.land/x/attain/mod.ts";
const app = new App();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hey there!");
});

app.listen({port: 8080});
```

It looks promising to start using it as a middleware framework, but I am looking for an experienced opinion about whether Attain contains the same internal functionalities as Express, and whether there are differences between them?

Comment: I'm not sure it's 100% compliant, and it's probably not going to be ever. You may give it a try though, just don't put all your money on it.

Comment: Looking at [the code](https://deno.land/x/attain/application.ts) and at sample apps, it looks very Express-like, but there are certainly differences.

Answer (score 2):

It's concepts and middlewares, and all the things are coming from the express.js concept. but the procedures are a little different. 
for one thing, Attain doesn't have next() method due to the fact that it is a step by step async based procedure. It will not stop until it faces the send() or end() method.

: GET method /

```js
import { App, Router } from "https://deno.land/x/attain/mod.ts";
const app = new App();

app.use((req, res) => {
  console.log("First step");
  
  res.whenReady(() => {
    console.log("Fourth step");
  });
});

app.get("/hello", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Second step but will skip it because of url unmatched.");
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Third step");
  res.status(200).send("The fifth step has responded.");
});

app.use((req, res) => {
  console.log("It does not reach here.");
});

app.listen({port: 8080});
```

I can say oak is highly expended and ready to use because it has been developed for a long time. But the Attain library has been released a few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the web framework that is the closest to Express with Deno is oak

https://github.com/oakserver/oak

If you are familiar with JavaScript middleware frameworks like Express and Koa it will be easy to understand and use

Answer (score 0):

The closes i get when finding a web framework for Deno is [OAK](https://deno.land/x/oak), its the most popular one out there that is available, other [abc](https://deno.land/x/abc) and [pogo](https://deno.land/x/pogo), but so far OAK is the best and goto with routers and middlewares.
You can find a detail article about [Building a simple REST API with Deno and OAK](https://medium.com/@aitsama.ahad/building-a-simple-rest-api-with-deno-and-oak-5b27a5740449) on medium for better understanding.